How to manage SQLAlchemy sessions across multiple pages in a Streamlit app?
Question:
I'm building a multi-page Streamlit app that interacts with an SQLite database using SQLAlchemy. Each page in my app performs various database operations like querying, inserting, or updating records.
Here's a simplified structure of my app:

Home Page: Handles user logins.
Page 1: Displays user data.
Page 2: Allows editing user profiles.

I initially set up a global SQLAlchemy session like this:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

# Create an engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///example.db')

# Create a session
session = Session(bind=engine)

But I quickly ran into issues when navigating between pages or performing multiple operations. Errors like the following often appear:
I suspect the problem is due to sessions not being properly isolated across threads or page interactions.
Problem:
How can I manage SQLAlchemy sessions effectively in a multi-page Streamlit app to ensure each page or user interaction gets a fresh, isolated session? Specifically, how should I structure session management to avoid conflicts and errors?
Desired Solution:

Thread-safe: Sessions should be thread-safe and isolated to avoid conflicts.
Ease of Use: Should integrate smoothly with Streamlit's state management.

Additional Context:

Streamlit version: 1.31.0
SQLAlchemy version: 2.0.25
Postgres Database

Any advice or best practices for handling this would be greatly appreciated!
What I've Tried:

Using a Global Session: Led to transaction state errors.
Re-initializing Sessions: Creating a new session on each page manually, but it feels cumbersome and error-prone.

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This session is in 'committed' state; no further SQL can be emitted within this transaction.

InvalidRequestError: Object <Case at 0x...> is already attached to a session '34' (this is '70')


There is a lot to unpack here,
and the errors may not be because of your session management. Without a stacktrace and the original code, I can't help.
My short suggestion would be to use st.session_state to store your SQLAlchemy session accross multiple pages. (Do NOT use global, it is not a substitute)
if "db_session" not in st.session_state.keys():
    st.session_state.db_session = Session(bind=engine)

I've used this method in 5+ streamlit applications.
Remember that streamlit reruns the script on each interaction with the page. That means that if you don't store your session in the session_state, you will be creating a new session for each interaction.
About it being thread-safe: This part seems GPT generated, but the only way for the session to not be thread safe, is to use a streamlit extension for a server state and save your session there (NOT RECOMMENDED).
